# How to iterate an iterator continuously and count number of cycles

Tags: python, loops, iterator, python-itertools

I am looking for a pythonic way to iterate over iterator continuously, but also keep track of how many cycles I go through. I want something like `itertools.cycle` but with a counter.

My goal:

```
import numpy as np
iterator = np.linspace(1,100, 0.1)

for n, val in count_cycle(iterator)

    if not n%10:
         some_function(val)

    some_other_function(val)

    if n == 1600:
        a_third_function(val)
```

Comment: `enumerate(np.linspace(1, 100, .1))` ?  enumerate works just fine with iterators.

Comment: Thanks! this works with `itertools.cycle`.  e.g. `for i, c in enumerate(cycle(np.arange(1,10,1))):`

Comment: Bonus points for anybody who can figure a nicer way of counting just the cycles (not each loop). For the example above, that would mean `n` increases every 10th loop. Modulo arithmetic will work but it would be cleaner to have it all nicely contained.

Comment: Why 10?  Just because?

Comment: `itertools.izip(cycle(range(10)), cycle(your_iterator))`